# If a variable = content in a txt file

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I need way to make this work:

```
if(variable.indexOf(textfilescontent)
    do this
else
    do this
```

I dont know how to im just started working with `discord.js` and javaScript so if there is someone who knows how to do this please reply to this post(this is my last try...)!

EDIT:im trying to check if the textfile has the same text in it with the variable

EDIT: the code im trying to make will do this as a whole: it will get the latest yt channels video(done) as entry.link. after that it would(this is the part im not sure how to do) check if a txt file has the same link. If it does not have the same link it means the video is updated=it will post a message to discord with the link in it. If yes it will get the link again and try the same thing again.(i know how to do the discord part but i dont know how to do the check if txtfilecontent=variablecontent

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you asking but I'm going to assume you want to check if the contents of the file is located somewhere in the variable. If this is the case then you can do:

```
  (async () => {
     let InFile = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let file = require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/FILE_NAME.EXTENSION');

        if(String(VAR_NAME).indexOf(file) > -1) {
           resolve(this);
        }else {
           reject(this);
        }
     });

     InFile.then(async () => {
        console.log('It is in file...');
        // Code You Want To Execute If The File Is In The Varible
        // You May Or May Not Want To Use The "async" keyword depending on the code that goes in here
     }).catch(async () => {
        console.log('It isn\'t in file...');
        // Code You Want To Execute If The File Is Not In The Varible
        // You May Or May Not Want To Use The "async" keyword depending on the code that goes in here
     });
  })();
```

Apologies in advanced for if this is not what you were asking for.

**EDIT:** Before you can run this code, you must type "npm install --save fs" into your terminal while in the directory of your project

Comment: Thanks for the answer i will look at it soon!

Comment: Thats what i need! but it does not work... first it prints it is in file and it should return after that but the it prints it isnt in file?!

Comment: That is very odd because it is working for me perfectly. Try updating node if it isn't up to date.